# MPMusicPlayer inaccurate currentPlaybackTime for VBR audio

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avfoundation, mpmusicplayercontroller

When I seek to a position in a non-vbr mp3 by setting MPMusicPlayer's currentPlaybackTime property, I'm able to seek accurately. When I seek to the same position with a VBR mp3, it seeks to a further position in the audio file. The difference between the accurate seek position and given seek position seems to increase the further into the VBR file I seek.

Is this a known quirk of MPMusicPlayer? Is there a way around it using MPMusicPlayer or do I have to decode to PCM to get accurate seeking in VBR audio?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but this behavior is unfortunately not unheard of. A colleague of mine had the same problem in windows (don't know which framework, my guess is directShow). IIRC it was only a problem with *some* VBR files. I think it was an encoder setting that caused this. Files didn't have correct length in their headers or something. Sorry I am so vague, but maybe it's consoling that you're not alone.

Comment: Thanks for the consolation :) Indeed it looks like there are issues seeking VBR on many platforms. I didn't realize it's only with some VBR files though.

Comment: If you ever find out what's causing tis, and/or how to solve it, I would be interested in an answer, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

its too late, but I currently have the same problem, this thread [Why does MPMoviePlayerController setCurrentPlaybackTime goes to the wrong time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364147/why-does-mpmovieplayercontroller-setcurrentplaybacktime-goes-to-the-wrong-time) is speaking about a similar thing, but I cannot use the solution presented there, may be you can :)

P.S: if you've already found a different solution please post it here that we can learn it too :)